# How to create Allure report with Allure Gradle plugin when tests are failing?

Tags: gradle, testing, gradle-plugin, allure

I am using the [Allure Gradle plugin](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-gradle).

I have only one test in my Gradle project.

I perform the following Gradle command:

```
gradle allureReport --depends-on-tests
```

When the test is successful, the Allure report gets generated successfully into `build/reports/allure-report`.

However, when the test fails, no report is generated. Which makes sense, since the Gradle build is failing before report generation.

This is the error message:

```
> Task :remote-test:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':remote-test:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at:
```

How can I create the Allure report when tests are failing in Gradle?

Comment: I guess you need `--continue` gradle argument